# 'Come on, it's time to go home' here home is an adverb or noun?

Tags: nouns, adverbs, parts-of-speech

I have 2 options. A) Noun B) adverb then what should be the answer.

Comment: Traditional grammars would say that _home_ in the sentence above is a **noun adverb**; modern grammars **preposition.**

Comment: It's a preposition [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/home)

Comment: Derived from a noun. Used as a locative with a movement verb.

Comment: It's a directional particle(here used in a distal sense) with semantic weight. Lumping it with either adverbs or prepositions calls for drastic redefining (which some have done and claimed as law).

Comment: See also: [Can 'home' be an adjective as well as an adverb or a noun?](//english.stackexchange.com/q/385396)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test each possibility by substitution with words that you are confident are nouns, adverbs and so on.

Noun: “it’s time to go * *car*” - this doesn’t work.

Adverb: “it’s time to go *quietly*” - this is grammatical, but *quietly* provides the manner of going while *home* in the original quote doesn’t.

Preposition: “it’s time to go up” - this is grammatical and carries something of the sense of the original.

So “home” acts as a preposition in your example (as noted by several commenters to your question).

Comment: It doesn’t modify go? What is it related to, in any way, if not *go*?

Comment: @Xanne Oops, good catch; my mistake. Corrected.

Comment: @Lawrence— Isn't that what you'd written previously? : _It modifies go_?

Comment: @user405662 No, previously I said *home* didn’t modify *go*.

Comment: @Lawrence— I see. So the same holds for _Stay home_ as well, where _home_ is a preposition again, right? And if that's so, what is the new definition of _preposition_? (I gather from past posts here and elsewhere that it's a fairly new perspective of labeling POS, thanks largely to Otto Jespersen.)

Comment: @user405662 Yes, prepositions normally provide the relative 'position' of one noun to another (e.g. "he was near the fire" - "near" situates him with respect to the fire). "Home" kind of captures both the 'object' and the position. It has a sense of 'to somewhere', with the 'directional' component allowing the 'preposition' label.

Comment: @user405662 Actually, belay that. There might be a somewhat fuzzy line between adverb and preposition where "home" is concerned. I see that you've started a [new question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/563439/142322) about this, so I'll leave fuller treatment of this to be done there.